# Set-ADUser skip empty cells from xlsx

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to bulk update our users on DC from .xlsx, but the script should skip empty values from xlsx data.

I already tried it with several methods but doesn't work.

First try was with

```bsh
hash.GetEnumerator() | foreach {
    if ($_.Value -eq "") {
        $hash.Remove($_.Key)
    }
}
```

Secound try is as followed in code below:

```bsh
foreach ($h in $hash.Keys) {
    if ($(hash.Item($h)) -eq "") {
        $hash.Remove($h)
```

```cs
try {
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory -ErrorAction Stop -WarningAction Stop
} catch {
    Write-Host "ActiveDirectory module not found!!" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black
    Write-Host "Script Aborted." -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black
    # Abort the script.
    break
}

try {
    $credential = Get-Credential

    [Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 'en-US'
    #Declare file path and sheet name
    $file = "...\UpdateUsers_test.xlsx"
    #Create an Excel.Application instance and open that file
    $Excelobject = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $Workbook = $Excelobject.Workbooks.Open($file)
    $sheetName = "Sheet1"
    $sheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetName)
    #$objExcel.Visible=$true

    #Count max row
    $rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).Count
    #Count max column
    $colMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Columns).Count
    $hash = @{}
    $server = "IP-Address"

    #Specify starting positions
    $row, $col = 1, 1
    $updatedCount = 0

    #loop for rows
    for ($i=1; $i -le $rowMax-1; $i++) {
        #loop for columns
        for ($c=0; $c -le $colMax-1; $c++) {
            #Get all columns values to a hash
            $hash += @{$sheet.Cells.Item($row, $col+$c).Text = $sheet.Cells.Item($row+$i, $col+$c).Text}

            foreach ($h in $hash.Keys) {
                if ($(hash.Item($h)) -eq "") {
                    $hash.Remove($h)
                }

                #Create an object and assign hash keys as object property
                $Object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $hash

                #Get User via SamAccountname
                $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($Object.UserName)'" -
SearchBase 'DC=Domain, DC=local' -Server $server -Credential $credential

                #Set Users attribute with matched object attribute
                $user | Set-ADUser -DisplayName $Object.Displayname `
                    -OfficePhone $Object.PhoneNumber `
                    -EmailAddress $Object.email `
                    -Postalcode $Object.Postalcode `
                    -City $Object.City `
                    -Streetaddress $Object.Streetaddress `
                    -Country $Object.Country `
                    -Office $Object.Office `
                    -Title $Object.Title `
                    -Company $Object.Company `
                    -Department $Object.Department `
                    -Manager $Object.Manager `
                    -Mobile $Object.Mobile `
                    -Fax $Object.Fax

                #If you want to edit Object common name, you can remove enable two lines
below.

                #$userguid = $user.ObjectGUID.Guid
                #$user | Rename-ADObject -NewName $Object.DisplayName -Server $server -
Credential $credential

                $hash = @{}
                Write-Host $User.Name "- User attributes have been updated." -
ForegroundColor Yellow
                Start-Sleep -s 1
                $updatedCount += 1
            }

            Write-Host $updatedCount "Users have been updated" -ForegroundColor Green

            #close excel file
            $Excelobject.Quit()
        }

catch {
    Write-Error $_.Exception.ToString()
    Read-Host -Prompt "The above error occured. Press Enter to exit."
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. I think it would be a LOT easier if you export your Excel to a CSV file and use that for input. Powershell has excellent cmdlets for dealing with CSV while parsing through an Excel sheet using COM objects can be quite hard to do..

Comment: "Doesn't work" is an insufficient problem description. What do you expect the code to do, and what does it actually do? Also, the last code snippet you posted has several syntax errors (mostly, but not exclusively due to incorrectly wrapped lines). Please make sure that code in your question does not introduce new errors that aren't present in your actual code. The recommended procedure is to create a [mcve], verify that the code shows the same (erroneous) behavior as your real code, then post that code and the error(s) thrown by that code.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way of doing this is via the PSObject. Sometimes a record can have multiple properties and using a '' for searching for empty values might prove difficult.

Instead, you could use the PSObject property and search for null values:

```
$_.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {$_.Value}) -eq $null
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would advise you to use splatting rather than creating an object, which would involve using a hashtable to specify the parameters for `Set-ADUser`. To make this work the keys of your hashtable have to be the same as the parameters of the cmdlet. Yours are close, but there's a couple discrepancies, so first off we need to make a hashtable to map your spreadsheet to the right parameters. Put this before your loop for rows.

```
$ParamMap = @{
    Displayname = 'DisplayName' 
    PhoneNumber = 'OfficePhone' 
    email = 'EmailAddress' 
    Postalcode = 'Postalcode' 
    City = 'City' 
    Streetaddress = 'Streetaddress' 
    Country = 'Country' 
    Office = 'Office' 
    Title = 'Title' 
    Company = 'Company' 
    Department = 'Department' 
    Manager = 'Manager' 
    Mobile = 'Mobile' 
    Fax = 'Fax'
}
```

Now we slightly rework how you create your hashtable to use that to lookup key names (this would replace your `$hast +=` line):

```
                $hash.add($ParamMap[$sheet.Cells.Item($row, $col+$c).Text], $sheet.Cells.Item($row+$i, $col+$c).Text)
```

Now that we have a hashtable we can check for null or empty strings, and remove them.

```
                $hash.keys | Where{ [string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($hash[$_]) } | ForEach-Object { $Hash.Remove($_) }
```

That line enumerates the keys for `$hash`, and checks the value for each key to see if it contains a null value, or only whitespace (spaces, tabs, new line). If it is null or whitespace it removes that key from the hashtable.

Now that we have a hashtable that only has valid keys that represent parameters for the cmdlet, and each key has a value we splat that to the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet and we're all set.

```
                $user | Set-ADUser @hash
```

Answer (score 0):

@TheMadTechnician 
 Thanks!
 Your answer helped me a lot. But I still have issues to pass the hashtable to the Set-ADUser cmdlet. 
 Unfortunately I'm not able to solve those error messages by myself

```
#loop for rows 
for ($i=1; $i -le $rowMax-1; $i++)
{

    #loop for columns
    for($c=0; $c -le $colMax-1; $c++)
    {
      #Get all columns values to a hash

      $hash += @{$sheet.Cells.Item($row, $col+$c).Text = $sheet.Cells.Item($row+$i, $col+$c).Text}

      $hash.keys.Clone() | Where{ [string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($hash[$_]) } | ForEach-Object { $Hash.Remove($_) }
      $hash | Out-String | Write-Host

    }


   #Create an object and assign hash keys as object property
   $Object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $hash

   #Get User via SamAccountname  
   $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($Object.SamAccountName)'" -SearchBase 'DC=domain, DC=local' -Server $server -Credential $credential 


}

   #Set Users attribute with matched object attribute
   $user | Set-ADUser   -Replace EmailAddress = $Object.Email; `
                        -Postalcode $Object.Postalcode `
                        -City $Object.City `
                        -Streetaddress $Object.Streetaddress `
                        -Country $Object.Country `
                        -Office $Object.Office `
                        -Title $Object.Title `
                        -Company $Object.Company `
                        -Department $Object.Department `
                        -Manager $Object.Manager `
                        -Mobile $Object.Mobile `
                        -Fax $Object.Fax
```

> System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException: Cannot bind parameter 'Replace'. Cannot convert the
>   "EmailAddress" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable". --->
>   System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidCastException: Cannot convert the "EmailAddress" value of type "System.String"
>   to type "System.Collections.Hashtable".
>      at System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives.ThrowInvalidCastException(Object valueToConvert, Type resultType)
>      at System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives.ConvertNoConversion(Object valueToConvert, Type resultType,
>   Boolean recurse, PSObject originalValueToConvert, IFormatProvider formatProvider, TypeTable backupTable)
>      at System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives.ConversionData`1.Invoke(Object valueToConvert, Type resultType,
>   Boolean recurse, PSObject originalValueToConvert, IFormatProvider formatProvider, TypeTable backupTable)
>      at System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives.ConvertTo(Object valueToConvert, Type resultType, Boolean
>   recursion, IFormatProvider formatProvider, TypeTable backupTypeTable)
>      at System.Management.Automation.ParameterBinderBase.CoerceTypeAsNeeded(CommandParameterInternal argument, String
>   parameterName, Type toType, ParameterCollectionTypeInformation collectionTypeInfo, Object currentValue)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception
>   exception)
>      at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
>      at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
>      at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)